# Vaadin Designer Theme Selector doesn't support custom theme

Tags: java, sass, vaadin, vaadin7

I just started using Vaadin Designer, and the theme selector doesn't show my custom theme. When I run the application the theme changes are applied and work fine, but I cannot see them instantly in Vaadin Designer.

Does anyone know where the themes are sourced?

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

$v-app-background-color: #fff;

@mixin octheme {
  @include valo;

  .valo-menu-title {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you import the project?

If it is a Maven project you should import the project as a Maven project so you get the project facets correctly configured. From the screenshot it looks like the project has been imported as a standard project.

You can try to add the facets later on as well. If you go to Project settings and Facets ensure you have the **Java** and **Dynamic Web Module** facets activated.

[image]